# Return the k elements of an array farthest from val

Tags: java

Method needs to return the k elements a[i] such that ABS(a[i] - val) are the k largest evaluation. My code only works for integers greater than val. It will fail if integers less than val. Can I do this without importing anything other than java.util.Arrays? Could somebody just enlighten me? Any help will be much appreciated!

```
 public static int[] farthestK(int[] a, int val, int k) {// This line should not change
  int[] b = new int[a.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
     b[i] = Math.abs(a[i] - val);
  }
  Arrays.sort(b);
  int[] c = new int[k];
  int w = 0;
  for (int i = b.length-1; i > b.length-k-1; i--) {       
     c[w] = b[i] + val;
     w++;     
  }
  return c;    
}
```

test case:

```
  @Test public void farthestKTest() {
         int[] a = {-2, 4, -6, 7, 8, 13, 15};
         int[] expected = {15, -6, 13, -2};
         int[] actual = Selector.farthestK(a, 4, 4);
         Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
       }

 There was 1 failure:
 1) farthestKTest(SelectorTest)
 arrays first differed at element [1]; expected:<-6> but was:<14>
 FAILURES!!!
 Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top k problem can be solved in many ways. In your case you add a new parameter, but it really doesn't matter.

The first and the easiest one: just sort the array. Time complexity: O(nlogn)

```
public static int[] farthestK(Integer[] a, final int val, int k) {
    Arrays.sort(a, new java.util.Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return -Math.abs(o1 - val) + Math.abs(o2 - val);
        }
    });
    int[] c = new int[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i];
    }
    return c;
}
```

The second way: use a heap to save the max k values, Time complexity: O(nlogk)

```
/**
 * Use a min heap to save the max k values. Time complexity: O(nlogk)
 */
public static int[] farthestKWithHeap(Integer[] a, final int val, int k) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(4,
            new java.util.Comparator<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                    return Math.abs(o1 - val) - Math.abs(o2 - val);
                }
            });
    for (int i : a) {
        minHeap.add(i);
        if (minHeap.size() > k) {
            minHeap.poll();
        }
    }
    int[] c = new int[k];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        c[i] = minHeap.poll();
    }
    return c;
}
```

The third way: divide and conquer, just like quicksort. Partition the array to two part, and find the kth in one of them. Time complexity: O(n + klogk)
The code is a little long, so i just provide link here.

[Selection problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)

Comment: Is there a reason you've changed `int` to `Integer` here?

Comment: @ChrisHayes Custom comparator could only used to compare Objects, so i have to change int[] to Integer[], you can also do this copy inside the method.

Comment: @Override  What does this mean? Can you make the code more clear?

Comment: @catchwisdom you could try to learn more about Comparator in java. You always need to write your own Comparator to sort different arrays. Override is just a annotation, means that this method override a parent method or implement an interface.

Comment: @catchwisdom You're going to need to be more specific. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thanks! How about I want the nearestK elements?

Comment: @catchwisdom, you just need to negative the result of compare(). i.e. change -Math.abs(o1 - val) + Math.abs(o2 - val)  to   Math.abs(o1 - val) - Math.abs(o2 - val)

Comment: I appreciate it! Looking through all answers I really learn a lot. Thank you guys and stackoverflow!

Comment: import java.util.Comparator; Do I need to do this on top of the code?

Comment: @catchwisdom, yes, you definitely should.

Comment: How can I do return farthestK without importing this? Just keep the first line (public static int[] farthestK(int[] a, int val, int k) { ) and only import java.util.Arrays?

Comment: @catchwisdom Change Comparator to java.util.Comparator. These are basic things in java. Need to learn more by yourself~~

Comment: This is a little part of homework. Professor doesn't allow us to modify the first line of the code. it must be " public static int[] farthestK(int[] a, int val, int k) { "

Comment: @catchwisdom ... Try to think by yourself since it's a homework... It's so easy to achieve your requirement, by adding a few lines.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36759/discussion-between-catchwisdom-and-faylon)

Answer (score 2):

Sorting the array will cost you **O(n log n)** time. You can do it in **O(n)** time using k-selection.

1. Compute an array B, where B[i] = abs(A[i] - val). Then your problem is equivalent to finding the k values farthest from zero in B. Since each B[i] >= 0, this is equivalent to finding the k largest elements in B.
2. Run k-selection on B looking for the (n - k)th element. See [Quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) on Wikipedia for an O(n) *expected* time algorithm.
3. After k-selection is complete, B[n - k] through B[n - 1] contain the largest elements in B. With proper bookkeeping, you can link back to the elements in A that correspond to them (see pseudocode below).

Time complexity: O(n) time for #1, O(n) time for #2, and O(k) time for #3 => a total time complexity of `O(n)`. (Quickselect runs in O(n) expected time, and there exist complicated worst-case linear time selection algorithms).

Space complexity: `O(n)`.

Pseudocode:

```
farthest_from(k, val, A):
  let n = A.length

  # Compute B. Elements are objects to
  # keep track of the original element in A.
  let B = array[0 .. n - 1]
  for i between 0 and n - 1:
    B[i] = {
      value: abs(A[i] - val)
      index: i
    }

  # k_selection should know to compare
  # elements in B by their "value";
  # e.g., each B[i] could be java.lang.Comparable.
  k_selection(n - k - 1, B)

  # Use the top elements in B to link back to A.
  # Return the result.    
  let C = array[0 .. k - 1]
  for i between 0 and k - 1:
    C[i] = A[B[n - k + i].index]

  return C
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking through it right now. I will get back to you later.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this algorithm a little and use it for printing k elements according to your requirement.(This is the only work you will need to do with some changes in this algorithm.)

**Explore this link.**
http://jakharmania.blogspot.in/2013/08/selection-of-kth-largest-element-java.html

This algo uses Selection Sort - so the output would be a Logarithmic Time Complexity based answer which is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`O(n)` algorithm, from Wikipedia entry on [partial sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting):

Find the k-th smallest element using the linear time [median-of-medians selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm). Then make a linear pass to select the elements smaller than the k-th smallest element.

The collection in this case is created by taking the original array, subtracting the given value, taking the absolute value, (and then negating it so that largest becomes smallest).